# how to run windows media player video in my html i am getting error Code attached?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, windows-media-player

i am new bie and i am getting error in running video in my html as i am using IE 8 and my code is here,

```
<OBJECT id="VIDEO"  
CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
type="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="Peace1.wmv" VALUE="Peace1.wmv">
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
<PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
<PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999">
</OBJECT>
```

please help me out thnaks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <object width="100%" height="100%"  type="video/x-ms-asf" url="Peace1.wmv" data="Peace1.wmv" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
  <param name="url" value="Peace1.wmv">
  <param name="filename" value="Peace1.wmv">
  <param name="autostart" value="1">
  <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
  <param name="autosize" value="1">
  <param name="playcount" value="1"> 
  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Peace1.wmv" width="100%" height="100%"    autostart="true" showcontrols="true" 

pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```

Try ablove code and let me know

Comment: one thing more i wanna know that if i am getting many videos from db then how would i use fwd and rew button for the next video ???